# How to convert str to int python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I have a function `max_population` which should output `('eu_kyiv', 24834)`. But output`('eu_kyiv', '24834')`

How can I do that  `('24834')` outputted as `int`

My code:

```
import re

def max_population(data):
    a = []
    for i in data:
        b = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', i)
        a += [[ b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]
return max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))


data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
        "3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
        "3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
        "3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
        "4892,me_medina,18038,n",
        "4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
        "4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
        "4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
        "6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]

print(max_population(data))
```

I tried

```
 for i in data:
        b = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', i)
        a += [[ int(b) for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]
 return max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

But output error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'eu_kyiv'`

It is important to use re module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def max_population(data):
    a = []
    for i in data:
        b = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', i)
        a += [[b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]

    maximum = max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
    return [maximum[0],int(maximum[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy. Not sure what is it that you don't understand. It is your `max` function. You do tell it to compare using second index as `int` and that it will but the output will be the exact values it compared using the defined key. So you just get the output then manually change it to int.

```
def max_population(data):
    a = []
    for i in data:
        b = re.findall(r',\S+_\S+,[0-9]+', i)
        a += [[ b for b in i.split(',') if b] for i in b]
    res = max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
    return res[0], int(res[1])
```

Comment: It doesn't work ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list '```

Comment: @ИльяГринишин edited the answer. I forget to return res and instead returned a. XD

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing int(x[1]) when you should be doing int(x[2]), because the first element is at 0

x[0] is 3024

x[1] is eu_kyiv

x[2] is 24834

so try 
return max(a, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the `csv` module to get the `poppulation` value:

```
>>> data = ["id,name,poppulation,is_capital",
...         "3024,eu_kyiv,24834,y",
...         "3025,eu_volynia,20231,n",
...         "3026,eu_galych,23745,n",
...         "4892,me_medina,18038,n",
...         "4401,af_cairo,18946,y",
...         "4700,me_tabriz,13421,n",
...         "4899,me_bagdad,22723,y",
...         "6600,af_zulu,09720,n"]
>>>
>>> import csv
>>> max(int(row['poppulation']) for row in csv.DictReader(data))
24834
```

If it's important to use the `re` module as well, this is an easy way to slide it in there:

```
>>> import re
>>> max(int(re.match(".*", row['poppulation'])[0]) for row in csv.DictReader(data))
24834
```